# EF Core Logging: What does the millisecond specification include in RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] entry?

Tags: performance, logging, entity-framework-core

I am analyzing a log file produced by EF core SensitiveDataLogging in order to find optimizable aspects of the project which uses Ef Core 7.0 with an sqlite db.

I tried to find information on log items like

```
dbug: [...] RelationalEventId.DataReaderDisposing[20300] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      A data reader for 'main' on server 'file.sqlite' is being disposed after spending 432ms reading results.
```

In the line quoted, what do the 432ms include?
is this meant literally? i.e. reading the queried results?
or does it also include other processes, if so, which ones?